# Getting duplicate rows on subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

So this has been bothering me for some time because I feel like in MSSQL this query would run just fine but at my new job I am forced to use Oracle. I have a subselect in a query where I want to find all of the people not assigned to a survey. My query is as follows:

```
Select distinct * From GetAllUsers, getperms
    Where id not in (getperms.users) and Survey_ID = '1'
```

If there are three users in the getperms table I get three rows for each person in the the GETALLUsers table.

I guess I could do some kind of join and that's no problem, it's just really bothering me that this doesn't work when i think that it should.

Comment: how the two table GetAllUsers, getperms  are related .. ? which colums join a tbale to another?

Comment: getperms.users are based on the getallusers.id key

Comment: Help us help you - please provide the tables' structures, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks just horrible. First of all you are using a join syntax that has become out of date more than twenty years ago. Then you are using `NOT IN` where it doesn't make sense (your set contains just one value). Then I can hardly imagine that `DISTINCT` makes sense in your query. Or one of the two tables contains records that are exact duplicates, which it shouldn't. Is `Survey_ID` really a string? And as you are working with two tables, you should use qualifiers on your columns to indicate where they reside in, e.g. `GetAllUsers.id`. I assume that `Survey_ID` resides in `getperms`.

Your query properly written looks thus:

```
Select *
From GetAllUsers gau
Join getperms gp On gp.Survey_ID = '1' And gp.users <> gau.id;
```

But of course whether you write it this way or the other, it does exactly the same. And there is no difference whether you use it in Oracle or SQL Server. What is does is: get all combinations of GetAllUsers and survey-1 getperms, except for the matches. So every user will be in the results, each combined with almost every getperms record.

You say: "I want to find all of the people not assigned to a survey". That would rather be:

```
Select *
From GetAllUsers
Where id Not In (Select users From getperms Where Survey_ID = '1');
```

Comment: _Your query looks just horrible._ Thanks! Got it now.

Answer (score 2):

> I feel like in MSSQL this query would run just fine

It would not. In both Oracle and MS-SQL, an IN clause needs to be a static list of items or a subquery that returns one column, so you'd need something like:

```
Select distinct * 
    From GetAllUsers
    Where id not in (SELECT id FROM getperms.users) 
    and Survey_ID = '1'
```

Note that I took `getperms` out of the FROM since it produces a cross-join, which is why you get every combination of records from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following 3 methods,if you wanted to exclude the `getperms` users from `GetAllUSers` .

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
FROM GetAllUsers a
  LEFT JOIN  getperms b
    ON a.id=b.users
        WHERE b.users is null AND Survey_ID = '1'
```

OR

```
SELECT  DISTINCT * 
FROM GetAllUsers a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM  getperms b
                    WHERE a.id=b.users)
        AND Survey_ID = '1'
```

OR

```
SELECT  DISTINCT * 
FROM GetAllUsers 
  WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT users
                    FROM  getperms )
        AND Survey_ID = '1'
```